# Why does this string property work?

Tags: javascript

```
function decinumber(y){
    var x = document.getElementById("areafield");
    if (y.match("del")){
        x.value = x.value.substr(0,(x.value.length-1)); return;
    }
}
```

I want to remove the last character from the x string. Now this code right here actually works, but my question is that why does this work? It sounds weird, but I don't know why.
Since, in strings the first character is in position 0 not position 1, then the total length of that string minus 1 gives us the last character in that string not the one before the last one.

For example,consider this string-- "fireblow"

The length of this string is 8. "f" is at position 0, so 8-1 is 7, and that is the position of the last character "w" in that string not "o".

Comment: Check the docs: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/substr  The 1st param is where to start, and the 2nd is how many characters you want.  "fireblo" is 7 characters.  In JavaScript, [`substr`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/substr) and [`substring`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/substring) are two different functions.

Comment: You may be misunderstand how `substr()`works. You're not telling the method to return the characters between two indexes. You're telling it where to start, and how many chars to return. [[Oops. Too slow.]]

Comment: If you get 7 characters (from position 0, included, to position 0+7, excluded), you will remove the 8th character.

Comment: @Bergi: Except in this case, the 2nd param is the length, and not an index.

Comment: @Bergi: Fair enough, I was just trying to not confuse OP :D

Answer (score 1):

The second parameter states how many characters you want to grab. Since you want to grab the entire string of X minus one character, you take the lenght of the string and minus 1 from it.

So now your substring states...

> Grab 7 characters from this string starting at position 0.

To test this out and solidify your understanding try different combinations. Start at position 3, and take only two characters.

Answer (score 0):

substr(start_index, length);

If you do `("areafield").length` you get 9.  If you do `("a").length` you get 1.

So, if we start with the character in the first position (index 0), and go 8 characters, we get

```
a r e a f i e l
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8
```

Or with `("fireblow").length` we get 8, so with `.substr(0,(x.value.length-1))`

```
f i r e b l o
1 2 3 4 5 6 7
```

Answer (score 0):

This works because [`substr`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/substr) takes character 0 to the length of the string - 1 here

```
x.value = x.value.substr(0,(x.value.length-1));
```

See also, this [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/uAqm5/) -

```
var text = 'Help';
text = '<h1>' + text.substr(0,(text.length-1)) + 'lo</h1>';
```

and then `text === "<h1>Hello</h1>"`